# variance of inner product of vectors sampled from gaussian distribution?

Tags: linear-algebra, statistics, neural-networks

Suppose that we have 2 vectors such W and X $\in R^N$ that each element sampled from normal distribution $\mathcal{N}(0, 1)$, and the inner product $Z=W^T X$.

Why is variance $V[Z]$ equal to $N\sigma^2_{x}(\sigma^2_{w}+\mu^2_{w})$?

Its related with signal propagation in neural network, such that how variance of activation can propagate through layers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From independence $$E[X_iW_i]=E[X_i]E[W_i]$$

$$E[X_i^2W_i^2]=E[X_i^2]E[W_i^2]=(Var(X_i)+E[X_i]^2)(Var(W_i)+E[W_i]^2)$$

If $E[X_i]=0$, then we have

$$Var(X_iW_i)=Var(X_i)(Var(W_i) + E[W_i]^2)$$

and I am leaving the very last step to you.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply.

Comment: from independence, 
Var(X1Y1 + X2Y2 + .... + XnYn) = Var(X1Y1) + Var(X2Y2) + ... + Var(XnYn)
                                                    = N ( Var(XiWi) )  ???
I assume that Var(X1Y1)=Var(X2Y2)=...=Var(XnYn)

Comment: Anyway, E[Xi]=0 is not assumed in the paper im reading....it may be  a mistake in writing the paper.

Comment: I am not sure what is this $N(0,1)$ that is being stated.

Comment: Sorry I confused you. the state of my question is wrong. To be strict, W is i.i.d sampled from gaussian distribution, and X is i.i.d. sampled from N(0,1), and Z=W^T * ReLU(X).
Thus, we cannot assume ReLU(X) as N(0,1). I think there is any mistake in the paper.